# Install Windows 7 GRUB Error

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-7

I need to let my roommate borrow one of my laptops.  Unfortunately, Windows needs to be installed to this computer for him to operate normally.  I followed this guide to get a Windows 7 ISO to a boot-able USB - http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/create-bootable-windows-7-usb-drive.html

When I boot the laptop with this USB installed, I get this error:

`error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found`

`grub rescue>`

The target laptop is running Ubuntu Raring, and is 100% ext4.

Thanks in advance for any help!

- Nathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install winusb to create bootable windows usb from ubuntu.Run the following commands on terminal to install winusb,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install winusb
```

[image]

Comment: When I use winusb, it doesn't boot from usb.

Comment: After using winusb, I had to go into gparted and make the usb drive flagged as bootable.